# Notation for Expressing Hyperoperations and their Inverses

Tags: notation, inverse, hyperoperation

This is a table for the new mathematics notation alongside its equivalent old mathematics rendition:
\begin{align}
a *_1 b & \equiv a + b & & a \; /_1 \; b \equiv a - b & & a \; \backslash_1 \; b \equiv b - a \\
a *_2 b & \equiv ab & & a \; /_2 \; b \equiv \frac{a}{b} & & a \; \backslash_2 \; b \equiv \frac{b}{a} \\
a *_3 b & \equiv a^b & & a \; /_3 \; b \equiv \sqrt[b]{a} & & a \; \backslash_3 \; b \equiv \log_a b
\end{align}

I chose $*$ to represent "composition" operations as I think both $+$ and $\times$ are both fairly good symbolically speaking, so I decided to merge the two. I chose $/$ and $\backslash$ to denote the "decomposition" operations as they already commonly represent division and I think they do a good job in my mind showing how these operations almost act like incisions. The subscripts correspond to the $n$th hyperoperation and continue to unfold as such.

The "forward" decomposition operations (denoted as $/$) are defined as
$$
x_1 * x_2 = y \leadsto \\
y * x_2 = x_1 \leadsto \\
y = x_1 \; / \; x_2.
$$

Whereas "backwards" decomposition operations (denoted as $\backslash$) are defined as
$$
x_1 * x_2 = y \leadsto \\
x_1 * y = x_2 \leadsto \\
y = x_1 \; \backslash \; x_2.
$$

E.g.
$$
a \; /_3 \; b \equiv \sqrt[b]{a} \; \because \\
a *_3 b \equiv a^b \leadsto \\
a^b = y \leadsto \\
y^b = a \leadsto \\
y = \sqrt[b]{a}
$$

and

$$
a \; \backslash_3 \; b \equiv \log_a b \; \because \\
a *_3 b \equiv a^b \leadsto \\
a^b = y \leadsto \\
a^y = b \leadsto \\
y = \log_a b
$$

Hypothetically-speaking, this does imply  that there should be two $*$ operations, but I don't think that would be necessarily very useful.

Are there any problems with this notation? Are there any better notations out there for hyperoperations? All I've really seen for this type of thing are Knuth's up-arrow notation and Conway's chained arrow notation, but they don't exactly seem to cover the same use cases.  Please let me know if I got anything incorrect or I didn't explain something well enough.

Please note that I would have preferred to define $a \; \backslash_3 \; b$ as $\log_b a$, but it seems to have a weaker mathematical basis than the definition listed above.

Comment: In the second column I believe you meant to index them $1,2,3$ and not $1,1,1$. I tried to edit but it said my edit is too short. It should let you make the edit.

Comment: @Snaw Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: Perhaps it would be good to look at some special values, like "the null-element" (getting one of the two operands as the result, for addition this is $0$, for multiplication this is $1$ , for the other ones?), or something like an "infinity element" (for the addition the second argument does not matter) and so on. Such "special values" for the arithmetic surely shape the hierarchy of operations with more contour, perhaps similar to the "discussion of curves" in high school w.r. to their behave at infinity, at zero, at minimum, maximum etc.